# Run python 3.6 and 2.7 on the same computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have python 3.6 installed on my computer with Windows 10. Python 3.6 is in the path:

> C:\Users\linekm475\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32

and I added a path so it works to just type in "python" in cmd to open python 3.6 in cmd. And the problem I have now is that I want to have python 2.7 installed too so I can use both of them. So I installed python 2.7 and it's in the path:

> C:\Users\linekm475\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27

Is it possible to do so when I type something like "python27" in cmd that it opens up python 2.7?

Comment: Yes you can. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how?

Comment: Semi-related, look into using Anaconda. // Otherwise you can navigate to your desired python installation directory and run programs from there. Or you can provide the full path to Python when you run programs from other directories.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/150244/command-aliases-in-command-prompt) will help?

Comment: I have two versions of Python on my machine and they work fine. For Python 2, I do `py -2 myfile.py`. For Python 3, I do `py -3 myfile.py`.

Answer (score 1):

The `py` program is the best way to manage pythons on windows:

```
py -2 [commands]
py -3 [commands]

py -2 -m pip
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (assuming you're only doing this from the CLI) is to use a `doskey` alias.  In your case it would be something like

`doskey python27=C:\Users\linekm475\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27`

Please note that there are some serious limitations to doskey macros (most notably that it can only be used from the command line, not from a script or batch file, nor can they be used on either side of a pipe), but it will accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

1- You can use IDLE(python2.7) or IDLE(python3.6) seperately. You can use IDEs like PyCharm.

2- You can run your .py file from command promt, but you should set python2 and python3 [paths](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path) to your system.

Comment: How do I set those paths to my system?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7#4855685  
That should help you.